# PROBLEM WITH ELECTRON AND SQLITE3 INSTALL

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I am trying to install electron in my project, but it seems that there is a conflict with sqlite3 and I have not been able to solve it. Here is the log. I trying this:

"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
   ...
}

npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall

```
install-app-deps

  • please use as subcommand: electron-builder install-app-deps
  • electron-builder  version=22.3.2
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=sqlite3@4.1.1 platform=win32 arch=x64
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
                    out=
    > sqlite3@4.1.1 install C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

    Los proyectos de esta soluci�n se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilaci�n en paralelo, agregue el modificador "/m".   
      unpack_sqlite_dep
      El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" sali� con el c�digo 1. [C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
    Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.0-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v8.0' (1)

                    errorOut=node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
    node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.1.1/electron-v8.0-win32-x64.tar.gz       
    node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.1.1 and electron@8.0.1 (electron-v8.0 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23) 
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\devel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\devel\\Documents\\Proyectos\\Virtual_Assistant\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v8.0-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\devel\\Documents\\Proyectos\\Virtual_Assistant\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v8.0-win32-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=electron-v8.0"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3
    gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.0-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v8.0' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\devel\\Documents\\Proyectos\\Virtual_Assistant\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\sqlite3
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! sqlite3@4.1.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.1 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-23T18_00_38_702Z-debug.log

                    command='C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' 'C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' rebuild sqlite3@4.1.1
                    workingDir=
Error: C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\Virtual_Assistant\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:239:14)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Virtual_Assistant@1.2.0 postinstall: `install-app-deps`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Virtual_Assistant@1.2.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\devel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-23T18_00_38_871Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Found any solution yet?

Comment: No,i tried with npm run electron postinstall but doesn't works

Comment: Get the same error using Quasar, electron and sqlite3